# Could not able to figure out the error near convert sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

It is giving me an error saying **'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.'** Could not able to figure out what could be done to remove it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_convert_unix_timestamp]
    @table_name nvarchar(250),     ---Staging Table
    @DateTimeString nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
        if isnull(@DateTimeString,'') <> '' begin 
        declare @SQLString Nvarchar(max)    
        declare @UpdateString Nvarchar(max)
        declare @initialepoch Nvarchar(10)
        set @initialepoch = '19700101'
        SELECT @SQLString = coalesce(@SQLString + ',', '') + 
                            'convert(varchar, dateadd(ss, convert(Int, ' + value + '),' + @initialepoch + '), 120)'   
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DateTimeString, ',')  
        WHERE RTRIM(value) <> ''

        select @UpdateString = 'Update [' + @table_name  + '] set ' + @SQLString

        exec (@SQLString)
    end 
END
```

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` function didn't support in sqlserver 2008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)

Comment: STRING_SPLIT was added in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I have updated the tag. I am working on sql server 2016

Comment: The statement you are trying to execute is a CONVERT... which in fact isn't a statement but a function. It can be contained in a SELECT statement, but it can't be executed all alone.

Comment: I guess you mean value = convert() is needed.

Comment: Put a PRINT @SQLSTRING before the EXEC to get an idea of what it is attempting to execute.

Comment: Actually this script is being executed in an ETL tool which does not print the output of the script

Comment: I'd recommend `QUOTENAME` over `'[' + @table_name  + ']'`. What you have is still open to injection. For example `@table_name = 'MyTable]; USE master; ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE YourDatabase;--'` would work fine (Assuming `MyTable` and `YourDatabase` were real objects, and the Login had high enough priviledges.)

Comment: Using `QUOTENAME(@table_name)` would turn the string into `'[MyTable]]; USE master; ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE YourDatabase;--]'`, making it completely harmless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's fix the SP so it's no open to Injection, and the datatype choice for `@table_name`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_convert_unix_timestamp]
    @table_name sysname,     ---Staging Table
    @DateTimeString nvarchar(max)
AS

    IF ISNULL(@DateTimeString, '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(MAX);
        DECLARE @UpdateString nvarchar(MAX);
        DECLARE @initialepoch nvarchar(10);
        SET @initialepoch = N'19700101';

        SELECT @SQLString = COALESCE(@SQLString + ',', '') + N'convert(varchar(10), dateadd(ss, convert(Int, ' + QUOTENAME(value,N'''') + N'), + @dinitialepoch), 120)'
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DateTimeString, ',')
        WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';

        SELECT @UpdateString = N'Update ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + N' set ' + @SQLString;

        PRINT @UpdateString;
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, N'@dinitialepoch nvarchar(10)', @dinitialepoch = @initialepoch;

    END;
```

If we were to run that SP, `EXEC [dbo].[sp_convert_unix_timestamp] N'MyTable', N'20170720,20170721';`, you'd get this output (and magcially, you know the reason why it's not working):

```
Update [MyTable] set convert(varchar, dateadd(ss, convert(Int, '20170720'), + @dinitialepoch), 120),convert(varchar, dateadd(ss, convert(Int, '20170721'), + @dinitialepoch), 120)
```

There is no column in your `SET` clause. You simply have `UPDATE [Table] SET [Value];` The format of an `UPDATE` statement is `UPDATE [Table] SET [Column] = [Value];`. What column(s) that needs to be updated, however, I have no idea...